# How to Convert sql table data from several rows into only one row based on a single comparison on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate

I have a table that has **12 rows** for a given company representing the payments of the company on a certain month, the structure of the table has
numbers representing the month, so `January = [1]`, `February = [2]` etc.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblMonths](
    [Uid] int not null IDENTITY Primary KEY,
    [Id] [float] NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Days] [float] NULL,
    [Pay] [float] NULL,
    [1] [float] NULL,
    [2] [float] NULL,
    [3] [float] NULL,
    [4] [float] NULL,
    [5] [float] NULL,
    [6] [float] NULL,
    [7] [float] NULL,
    [8] [float] NULL,
    [9] [float] NULL,
    [10] [float] NULL,
    [11] [float] NULL,
    [12] [float] NULL
) ;

insert into [TblMonths] values
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    17,     3   ,0, 0   ,51,0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    18.6,   3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,56 ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    19.2,   5   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 96  ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    19.75,  4   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,79,0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    20,     2   ,0, 0   ,0, 40  ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    22.5,   2   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0,45,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    23.5,   2   ,47,0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    25,     2   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  50),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    26,     2   ,0, 52  ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    26.6,   3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,80,0   ,0, 0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    28.5,   2   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,57,0,  0),
(2, 'COMPANY_A',    29.3,   3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 88  ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    13.8,   5   ,0, 0   ,69,0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    15,     2   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,30 ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    16,     1   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0,16,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    20,     3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,60,0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    20,     4   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  80),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    20.5,   2   ,0, 0   ,0, 41  ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    23.25,  4   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0,93   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    23.3,   3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,70,0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    23.5,   2   ,47,0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    28,     1   ,0, 28  ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    29,     3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 87  ,0  ,0, 0   ,0, 0,  0),
(3, 'COMPANY_B',    29.3,   3   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0, 0   ,0  ,0, 0   ,88,0,  0);
```

I want to convert all **12** rows of each **Company_X** into only **1**, assigning the value of column `"Days"` when the value of the month column is different from `0`...

```
ID  COMPANY     JAN     FEB     MAR     APR     MAR     JUN     JUL     AGO     SEP     OCT     NOV     DEC
2   COMPANY_A   23.5    26      17      20      19.75   29.3    18.6    26.6    19.2    28.5    22.5    25
3   COMPANY_B   23.5    28      13.8    20.5    23.3    29      15      20      23.25   29.3    16      20
```

for instance `on row 7,` In `january` it has the value **47**, so I want to get the value on column `"Days"` that is **23.5**, in all other rows of `id=2`, there are `0` thats why I want to search the value different from `0`.

In the case of `february` on row `9` it has the value  **52** and column `Days` have **26**

In the case of `march` the first row has a value of **51** so I would like to take the value on column `"Days"` that is **17** so I would get something like:

```
ID  COMPANY     JAN     FEB     MAR...     
2   COMPANY_A   23.5    26      17
```

How does the script to do so look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume that for a  company and ID that no month would have more than 1 non-zero value...  If we can't assume would you want them Sum()'d together?  the Min or max value?  Just adjust the below accordingly.   Note: If min, we **may** have to leave out the 0 on the else and coalesce the 0 in after the min.

and now if you want zeros in the case where no col 1-12 has a value other than 0... we add a else  to each case statement.

[RexTester DEMO](https://rextester.com/UEDA97281)

```
SELECT ID
     , Company
     , max(case when [1] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as JAN
     , max(case when [2] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as FEB
     , max(case when [3] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as MAR
     , max(case when [4] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as APR
     , max(case when [5] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as MAY
     , max(case when [6] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as JUN
     , max(case when [7] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as JUL
     , max(case when [8] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as AUG
     , max(case when [9] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as SEP
     , max(case when [10] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as OCT
     , max(case when [11] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as NOV
     , max(case when [12] <> 0 then Days else 0 end) as DEC
FROM tblMonths
GROUP BY ID, Company;
```

Giving us:

```
+----+----+-----------+------+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+
|    | ID |  Company  | JAN  | FEB | MAR  | APR  |  MAY  | JUN  | JUL  | AUG  |  SEP  | OCT  | NOV  | DEC |
+----+----+-----------+------+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+
|  1 |  2 | COMPANY_A | 23,5 |  26 |   17 |   20 | 19,75 | 29,3 | 18,6 | 26,6 |  19,2 | 28,5 | 22,5 |  25 |
|  2 |  3 | COMPANY_B | 23,5 |  28 | 13,8 | 20,5 |  23,3 |   29 |   15 |   20 | 23,25 | 29,3 |   16 |  20 |
+----+----+-----------+------+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+
```

Granted I'm not use to two months named `MAR` and one called `AGO`  So I adjusted those.

Comment: What could happen if there are no value greater than zero in a month column? I mean, It would give null value but, in that case I would set 0 if that happened?

Comment: You'd get a null in that month.  you could coalese it to 0 or put a else 0 on all the cases.